# Different font displayed wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I use wicked_pdf gem in my project.

Everything was fine until I updated the version of the cut version of all gems.

Now the font in my pdf is displayed differently. With what it can be connected?

Also in my text appeared bold headers that were previously common.

The wicked_pdf gem was not updated.

Can the font change due to *wkhtmltopdf*?

Gem change log:

```
addressable (2.6.0)
public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
  addressable (2.7.0)
  public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
autoprefixer-rails (9.5.1)
  autoprefixer-rails (9.6.1.1)

bcrypt (3.1.12)
  bcrypt (3.1.13)

bootsnap (1.4.4)
  bootsnap (1.4.5)

capybara (3.18.0)
  capybara (3.28.0)

regexp_parser (~> 1.2)
  regexp_parser (~> 1.5)

domain_name (0.5.20180417)
  domain_name (0.5.20190701)

ffi (1.10.0)
  ffi (1.11.1)

jquery-rails (4.3.3)
  jquery-rails (4.3.5)

jwt (2.1.0)
  jwt (2.2.1)

mini_mime (1.0.1)
  mini_mime (1.0.2)

minitest-reporters (1.3.6)
  minitest-reporters (1.3.8)

mocha (1.8.0)
  mocha (1.9.0)

msgpack (1.2.10)
  msgpack (1.3.1)

multipart-post (2.0.0)
  multipart-post (2.1.1)

nio4r (2.3.1)
nokogiri (1.10.3)
  nio4r (2.5.1)
  nokogiri (1.10.4)

notiffany (0.1.1)
  notiffany (0.1.3)

pg_search (2.1.7)
  pg_search (2.3.0)

public_suffix (3.0.3)
puma (3.12.1)
  public_suffix (4.0.1)
  puma (4.1.0)

rack-protection (2.0.5)
  rack-protection (2.0.7)

rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
  rails-html-sanitizer (1.2.0)

rake (12.3.2)
 rake (12.3.3)

redis (4.1.0)
regexp_parser (1.4.0)
  redis (4.1.2)
  regexp_parser (1.6.0)

ruby-progressbar (1.10.0)
  ruby-progressbar (1.10.1)

sass-rails (5.0.7)
railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
  sass-rails (5.0.8)
  railties (>= 5.2.0)

twilio-ruby (5.22.3)
  twilio-ruby (5.25.4)

vcr (4.0.0)
webmock (3.5.1)
  vcr (5.0.0)
  webmock (3.7.0)

websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
  websocket-extensions (0.1.4)

wicked_pdf (1.1.0)
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this issue on github](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/721)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be [a known issue](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/721#issuecomment-429560752) with `wkhtmltopdf-binary`.

You might try locking to an earlier version.  In Gemfile

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '=0.12.3.1'
```